# SSH port forwarding

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I want to connect to my computer(local) behind NAT through a public accessible server(public).

On local:

```
ssh -g -R 8000:localhost:22 user@public
```

Then on public:

```
ssh -p 8000 user@public
```

But I am getting `error: Connection refused.`

When I login to the public server, I can verify that the tunnel is working by:

```
ssh -p 8000 localhost
```

Which opens ssh on the local computer.

Am I suspecting something wrong that the public server should act as transparent proxy? Or how to make it work like that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SSH remote port forwards will default binding to localhost/loopback for security purposes. It's not often preferable to allow other hosts access to your forwarded ports.

To override this behaviour you will need to do two things:

- Enable the `GatewayPorts` option on the server.
- Specify a bind address, or `*` to bind to all addresses, on the client.

  ```
  ssh -R \*:8000:localhost:22 user@public
  ```

Escape the asterisk to ensure that your shell doesn't expand it.

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like a problem with the settings on the remote computer public. By default the openssh sshd (which I guess is the one being used) the setting GatewayPorts turned to no, which forces remote port forwarding to only listen on localhost.

The solution would then be to edit your /etc/ssh/sshd_config (or equivalent), setting GatewayPorts to yes or to clientspecified. In case you choose the later you will have to change your tunnel request to something like -R *:8000:localhost:22 instead.