# ssh port forwarding is not available (locally) for IP rather localhost only

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I have a **remote** machine at `example.com` with `sshd` listening to port `1234`
and a web service at port `5678`.

For some reasons, I want to 'localize' the http requests to that web service.

When I execute

```
ssh -L 4321:example.com:5678 root@example.com -p 1234 -N
```

On the local machine (`10.0.0.1`), I can view the web service by navigating to:

```
http://localhost:4321
```

However, if I point the browser to:

```
http://10.0.0.1:4321
```

I get error (Error 102: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED if that makes any difference).

Is there a way to make the ssh port forwarding available under **`ip address`** rather than **`localhost`**?

I need it in order to have the remote service available for other computers on the LAN (10.0.0.0/24).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found this [SSH port forwarding](https://serverfault.com/questions/88141/ssh-port-forwarding/88148#88148)

```
ssh -L \*:4321:example.com:5678 root@example.com -p 1234 -N
```

is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

When using remote port forwarding, ensure that sshd_config on server has gateway ports enabled (GatewayPorts yes). Otherwise sshd will ignore the bind interface and only bind on localhost